# Excel VBA Unexpected Error 419 - Permission denied to use object

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with VBA programming, form activex controls, form controls. The spreadsheet has worked normally, until last week. I think the problem started when the automatic installation of windows uptade took place, however it might be only coincidence, since I am not positive if this is the cause. Now, the spreadsheet opens and immediately a small window appears that indicates :

> “Visual Basic for Applications - Permisson Denied to use object (OK,
>   Help)”. Selecting help, minimum information and it is irrelevant.
>   Selecting OK, another window pops out “Visual Basic for Applications -
>   Unexpected error 419 (OK, Help)”

I cannot even save the sheet to another name. The VBA code cannot run. If I open any new spreadsheet, Excel functions normally, also with its VBA. Just before having this problem, every time that I opened the spreadsheet a window appeared, indicating that Excel blocked the functionalities of the ActiveX controls and asking that if I would allow the use of ActiveX. Today, I enabled all macros and also all activex controls. My previous backups of this spreadsheet have also the same problem. None works. I went to VBA Edit-->References and compared the Libraries I had and the Libraries that are there on the spreadsheet. It seems that no library is missing. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions have changed on your workstation and/or network. Specifically, the folders that hold the DLL files that contain the objects referenced in the VBA. As an example (and I don't know if this is exactly the case, but an illustration), if your code is referencing the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* (many VBA projects do), your code needs permissions to access `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll`. (I found this by calling up the VBA editor, selecting Tools-->References, then selecting Microsoft Scripting Runtime and reading the bottom of the dialog window for the location.)

This is the location of the DLL on **my** workstation. Yours might be different or it might have moved during a systems update or the permissions to access that folder may have changed. You'll have to check the locations of all the references in your VBA project to determine this. Sometimes the libraries referenced are located on network drives, which can complicate matters if the network permissions change.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try to export all the forms (*.frm; *.frx). Everything went fine until I came across to a specific form that had a shockwaveflash object. At this point the message "Permission denied to use object". Bingo!

I then tracked the location on my workstation of such shockwave object reference and applied full administrator control. However, I still could not use shockwave objects. I then uninstalled flash and downloaded the lates shockwaveflash plugin from Adobe. When I open Excel->Developer->Insert->ActiveX Controls->More Controls -> ShockwaveFlashObject and then insert the object in a sheet, the message: "MS Excel - Cannot insert object" appears. I have manually deleted the "*.exd” from `C:\Users\[User ID]\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0`. Also deleted from `C:\Users\[User ID]\AppData\Local\Temp\VBE\`, but the problem was still there: "Microsoft Excel - Cannot insert object".

**To solve the issue** I finally accessed the VBA editor and deleted the userform that had the ShockwaveFlashObject in it. All went back to normal afterwards.